# Serilog Async File logging - how to add rolling

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, serilog

I am using latest `Serilog.File 4.1.0` and `Serilog.Sinks.Async`. Async logging works but I want the files to be rolled.
How can I enable rolling of files?

I have the following:

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Async(a =>
                {
                    a.File("logs/logs.log");
                })
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: I found it. For anyone out there with the same issue, I installed Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile replaced ```a.File("logs/logs.log");``` with ```a.RollingFile("logs/logs.log");```

Comment: post this as an answer so that people will be benefited.

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink My purpose was not to add this as an answer that is why I added it as a comment and another member prompted me to post it is as an answer. So I removed my answer and l am leaving the initial post

Answer (score 7):

The [`File`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) Sink has support for Rolling files. Just define your [rolling policies](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#rolling-policies).

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Async(a =>
    {
        a.File("logs/logs.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour); // <<<<<
    })
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .CreateLogger();
```